# Overflow problem in global asa and VB6 DLL

Tags: dll, vb6, com+

I ran into an issue when trying to debug a VB6 ActiveX dll. I have been able to get everything working to be able to debug, once I get the first call to an outside dll I get an Overflow error.

In the Global asa file here is the line of code that causes the issue. I unfortunately don't have access to the MBCUser code to see what is happening inside the Instantiate routine. I am not sure what is causing this and I have spent a long time doing research and have found nothing that has helped.

`Call oMBCUser.Instantiate(CStr(strUserID))`

If I comment this out of the asa file I am able to get to the point where I am creating the connection to the application. I get a type mismatch when I am trying to do this.

This is the call to the application

`Dim oConnection: Set oConnection = Server.CreateObject(CO_WFPConnection)`

Here is the function inside the application making the connection to the database

```
    Const cnMethodName = "GetConnection"
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler
    Dim dbADO As Object

    'Application ID is required
    theAppID = Trim$(UCase(theAppID))
    If (theAppID = "") Then
        ErrorText = "Application ID is Required"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set dbADO = CreateObject("MBCDB.DBADO")
    dbADO.Init (theAppID)
    Set GetConnection = dbADO
    Set dbADO = Nothing
    Exit Function

Errorhandler:
    Me.ErrorText = err.Description
    err.Raise err.Number & err.Description
End Function
```

Again I don't have Access to the MBCDB code to see what is going on be the problem occurs on the `dbADO.Init(theAppID)` line.

I have no idea what is going on and would love to hear peoples thoughts on this.

I am aware that I might have done something wrong in the setup of the COM+ objects as this isn't my specialty.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense and I will do my best to add more information.

I am on Windows 10 enterprise, VB6 sp6 and using IIS 10.0.

Comment: What is Instantiate() supposed to be doing? For instance, does it expect a numeric value in the string but in fact it gets something out of range, leading to the error? Its kind of impossible to debug without knowing what that procedure does.

Comment: I know what you mean, if I was able to get that code I might not be in the situation that I am in now. I don't think it is expecting numeric value as the whole point of that DLL is to confirm 4 digit user IDs.

Comment: This is a brute force approach... but if you tried a large range of possible inputs to Instantiate(), you might eventually see a pattern of success/failure which could be a useful clue. Good luck!

Comment: I tired a bunch of different values, one of them being empty and they all fail.

Comment: They all failed the same way, with an overflow?  If so, could there be some other data source (config file for instance) that isn't setup correctly, causing it to fail?

Comment: You were right, I finally managed to find the config file that I was missing and that allowed me to get it work.

Comment: Awesome, I'm sure that was a big relief! Glad you found the problem.